# moving from javascript window.open to Rich:ModalPanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In my web application currently there are many pop up windows made by various JS function which i would like to replace with Rich:ModalPanel (I'm using Myfaces 2.0.12 and RichFaces 3.3.3). Below is a typical example i like to replace:

```
   window.open("<%=basePath1%>jsp/custhistory.faces?userid="+pk);
```

where `pk` is the value retried from a hidden input such as  `<h:inputHidden id="userPk" value="#{1234}"/>` inside the javascript function and then added to the end of the url above.

Looking at few RichFaces ModalPanel examples (and demos) i can't figure out how i can make the above work using ModalPanel. Can someone please provide an example or a link to a resource o

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Richfaces 4, but the same theory should apply.

The modal panel is essentially a div that can be shown or hidden, so you could add a `<ui:include>` in there if you specifically need (or want) the panel to be a seperate file.

The modal panel is rendered as part of your page, but is styled as `display:none` I believe. If this is triggered by a client action you can call the Richfaces API to show the panel on command.

For instance instead of a command(Link|Button) triggering `Richfaces.$('elName').show()` it could trigger your js function which sets and values/params your modal panel needs and then call `.show()` itself.

Note: IE and firefox had a truly modal popup. This is not truly modal and javascript will process in the background, and if you do not give focus to the popup panel if the user types it will interact with the application in the background.

I had used a modal js popup to prompt a user with a yes/no question int his type of idiom

```
if(askUser("some question?")=='yes'){
    //some code to do if yes
}else{
    //some code to do if no
}
```

Depending on how generic you want this popup, that is not really possible without using an event that is fired and defining an event handler for that event to handle the rest of the function.